# Print a SOAP POJO to the String

Tags: java, xml, soap

I have a SOAP Pojo object provided below:

As it doesn't have any toString method, How do I print the POJO to the String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try static method of ReflectiveToStringBuilder with recursive style from Apache
`org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder#toString(java.lang.Object, org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle)`
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/RecursiveToStringStyle.html

Comment: This seems very useful. I will try and update an answer here.